# Problem with quotes and AtEndDocument

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation, babel, german

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,quotes,angles}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}


\newtheorem{pr}{Problem}
\newtheorem{solinn}{ad Problem}

\newtoks\prsoltoks

\NewEnviron{Solution}{%
  \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks\begin{solinn}}%
    \global\prsoltoks=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\prsoltoks\BODY\end{solinn}}%
}


\usepackage{multicol}
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\begin{center}\Large Solutions \end{center}
  \setcounter{pr}{0}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \the\prsoltoks
  \end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pr}~

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);%
  \coordinate (P) at (0,2);%
  \coordinate (Q) at (2,2);%

  \draw (O) -- (P);%
  \draw (O) -- (Q);%

  \pic["$\alpha$",draw,angle radius=1.5cm] {angle=Q--O--P};%"
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pr}

\begin{Solution}~
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);%
  \coordinate (P) at (0,2);%
  \coordinate (Q) at (2,2);%

  \draw (O) -- (P);%
  \draw (O) -- (Q);%

  \pic["$\alpha$",draw,angle radius=1.5cm] {angle=Q--O--P};%"
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Solution}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);%
  \coordinate (P) at (0,2);%
  \coordinate (Q) at (2,2);%

  \draw (O) -- (P);%
  \draw (O) -- (Q);%

  \pic["$\alpha$",draw,angle radius=1.5cm] {angle=Q--O--P};%"
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I comment out the "Solution" part, it works, else I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.72 \end{document}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

That's the same problem you get everytime if you don't load the babel library.

How can I fix this? Is there another way to set the label in the pic command than using the quotes library?

If I use the option `ngerman` of the article class everything works, but I want to use the babel package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside a `tikzpicture` environment the character `"` is not a shorthand marker any more, but when this is absorbed in the solutions it still is.

Workaround:

```
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\begin{center}\Large Solutions \end{center}
  \setcounter{pr}{0}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \scantokens\expandafter{\the\prsoltoks}%
  \end{multicols}
```

This makes TeX look at the tokens as if they were input from a file, so category codes are not fixed any more.